# Disabling a click event from the child of a parent div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to add a on click event to a `div` with a class parent. Now inside that `div` I have a `div` with class child that has its own click event.

How can I manage to disable the click event of the parent function for that child element in order to execute the function of child element itself?

I have tried using `pointer-event:none;` but it does not seem to be working. I have wrote a jsfiddle for better understanding.

https://jsfiddle.net/arq1epbs/

```js
$(document).on('click', '.parent', function() {
  var url = $(this).attr("data-url")
  document.location.href = url
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent" data-url="www.google.com">
  Im the parent
  <div class="child">
    im the child and I don't want to go to Google
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for all the help in advance!

Comment: `I have a div with class child that has its own click event.` the example does not show how/when you register that click even to the child.

Comment: I like the idea of a licking event, I think that this confinement made us all very frustrated ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `stopPropagation()`:

```
 $(document).on('click', '.parent', function () {
    var url = $(this).attr("data-url")
    document.location.href = url 
});
 $(document).on('click', '.child', function (e) {
 e.stopPropagation();
});
```

As it's not working in the Stack Snippet, here a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eaz02och/)
For reference: [stopPropagation()](https://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/#event-stopPropagation)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply call [`event.stopPropagation()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) inside child click event, to prevent the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the child click event like:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.parent', function() {
  //var url = $(this).attr("data-url")
  //document.location.href = url
  console.log('Parent Clicked');
});

$(document).on('click', '.child', function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  console.clear();
  console.log('Child Clicked');
});
```

```css
.parent{background:#99c0c3;width:350px;height:120px;position:relative}
.child{background:#ffde99;width:300px;height:50%;position:absolute;left:50%;top:50%;transform:translate(-50%,-50%)}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent" data-url="www.google.com">
  Im the parent
  <div class="child">
    im the child and I don't want to go to Google
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `to prevent the event from bubbling up the DOM tree` is a bit misleading in that context. Due to the event delegation used here, both events are captured at the document element, so the even already bubbled up the DOM, to the document element.

Answer (score 1):

Just add this line:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.parent', function (e) {
    if(e.target !== this) return false;   //This line added
    var url = $(this).attr("data-url")
    document.location.href = url 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent" data-url="www.google.com">
Im the parent
  <div class="child">
  im the child and I don't want to go to Google
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in "pure" JS

```js
document.querySelector('div.parent').onclick = evt =>
  {
  if (!evt.target.matches('div.parent')) return // reject sub elements click

  document.location.href = evt.target.dataset.url
  }
```

```css
div.parent { cursor: pointer }
div.child { cursor: default }
```

```html
<div class="parent" data-url="www.google.com">
  Im the parent
  <div class="child">
    Im the child and I don't want to go to Google
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should avoid using `onclick`, especially in a larger codebase.

Comment: @t.niese the advantage of onclick is that it refuses the use of other addEventListener on the same element and thus avoids any confusion in a too rough code

Comment: `onclick` does neither prevent to add further listeners using `addEventListener` nor does it override any event listeners already registered with `addEventListener`. It only overrides the event listener that was previously assigned to `onclick` and that's reason why it is problematic any real code.

Comment: @t.niese what you find problematic is precisely a useful constraint

Comment: In your own project is it's in the end up to you how you want to solve problems, as it is only you who has to deal with bugs and problems. But for larger projects that are used by others or on which multiple persons work, there are certain guidelines you should follow. The only benefit you have from `onclick` is to remove a listener from an element in a part of the code that does not own or know anything of that listener and for which you don't know why it exists or how to remove it in a different way.  If this is the case then you already have a conventional problem in the code.

Comment: @t.niese indeed, large projects or reigns a real anarchy on the management of events are a plague.